# How to count NaN rows against all ids in dataframe but nan will be consider by checking specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, jupyter-notebook

Context:

I have the Plantcube file which has 7 columns and that file is generated by the response of some device and every second that device response temperature or humidity and cube_id and timestamp is by default kind of thing never missed in all 400k records...

Question:

I want to find the count of ids where the device sends a response without temperature or humidity, finding id and their count will help me to trace cubes which having problems sending the response.

[image]

If you look at row no 3 Cube ID 48 and row no 5 Cube ID 90 does not have any information, so I want to count how many times id 48, 90, and others have the same situation.

Expected output eg:

Cube ID -> Missing Count

48 -> 1030

90 -> 790

400286 -> 36

File link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xZST8n27IcVsFor1qqu90jZ1E2cJ6pHb/view?usp=sharing

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mask1 = df['Temperature Layer A'].isna()
mask2 = df['Temperature Layer B'].isna()
mask3 = df['Humidity Layer A'].isna()
mask4 = df['Humidity Layer B'].isna()
df[mask1 & mask2 & mask3 & mask4]['Cube ID'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
16    1564
20    1561
45    1561
75    1560
21    1560
      ...
70    1537
40    1537
37    1536
10    1533
46     613
```

Comment: This is the correct this I was looking for and It's working...

Comment: my question is where all masks are false then it will count the Cuble ID

Comment: The masks help to select the values where at the row 'N' - 'Temperature Layer A', 'Temperature Layer B', 'Humidity Layer A' and 'Humidity Layer B' are NaN.  isna() returns True, if the values are NaN.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.isna.html) and [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df.loc[df.drop('CubeID',axis=1).isna().all(1)]['CubeID'].value_counts()
```